# Linq to SQL, concatenate fields without new dynamic type creation

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

I want to concatenate fields into one non-field which is a property of same model.

I have a model for `Person` which is include one non field property (NotMapped) called `FullName`:

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string firstname{get;set;}
   public string lastname{get;set;}

   [NotMapped]
   public string FullName{get;set;}
}
```

Now I want select all persons and their `FullName` which

```
FullName = string.format("{0} {1}",firstname, lastname);
```

I don't want to assign fullname per each person after listing table because has not good performance and speed (for ~10K records)

I don't want to using new select (dynamic type) as below

```
var list = from pf in db.Persons 
           select new 
                  {
                     Person = pf,
                     FullName = string.format("{0} {1}", pf.firstname, pf.lastname)
                  }
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

// bad performance
foreach(var item in list)
{
    item.Person.FullName = item.FullName;
    persons.Add(item);
}
```

Unless you offer me a dynamic lambda function for it with generic model type and expression for concatenate fields formula.

For example:

```
public List<TModel> GetList<TModel>(Expression<Func<TModel, string>> cField = null,...)
{
//all should done in database side with one query
//select all records include FullName
}
```

I don't want to using FullName.get

```
public string FullName
{
     get { return string.format("{0} {1}", pf.firstname, pf.lastname); }
}
```

because it is same as foreach method and has bad performance when you using that class in datagridview.

In another word, what I need is a linq query that select all person and their fullname.

Please note that any assignment after database select (specially when works with interface) has bad performance.

Comment: Can't you just use it as `public string FullName { get { return string.format("{0} {1}",firstname, lastname); } }`?

Comment: No! because fullname is a sample and what I need is a concatenate of more than 5 fields so processing FullName.get will takes valuable time. It will bind to a datagridview

Answer (score 1):

Change your model:

```
public class Person
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public string firstname{get;set;}
 public string lastname{get;set;}

 [NotMapped]
 public string FullName => firstname + " " + lastname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use some Dto for it

```
public class PersonDto
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public string FirstName{get;set;}
 public string LastName{get;set;}
 public string FullName{get;set;}
}
```

And select it like

```
db.Persons.Select(p => new PresonDto
                           {
                               Id = p.Id,
                               FirstName = p.firstname,
                               LastName = p.lastname,
                               FullName = p.firstname ?? "" + " " + p.lastname ?? ""
                           });
```

**EDIT**

In case if you don't want to use dtos and want more or less generic approach you I don't see any way to fill the property of an object during sql query. And select some Model into new Model() with reassigning all fields is not good idea.

So only way I can offer is to use some container to store your original Model and additional fields you want to select.

```
public class ItemAdditionalPropertyContainer<TModel>
{
    public TModel Item { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<ItemAdditionalPropertyContainer<TModel>> GetItemsWithAdditionalProperty<TModel>(
    IQueryable<TModel> items,
    Expression<Func<TModel, string>> additionalPropertySelector)
{
    Expression<Func<TModel, ItemAdditionalPropertyContainer<TModel>>> expr = 
        item => new ItemAdditionalPropertyContainer<TModel> 
            { 
                Item = item, 
                PropertyValue = additionalPropertySelector.Compile()(item)
            };
    return items.Select(expr.ExpandExpressions() );
}
```

But you have to use some expression expander as you can see. `expr.ExpandExpressions()` In order to allow LINQ compile it in correct way.

I used this one ([git link](https://github.com/mindbox-moscow/expressions)). Here's [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mindbox.Expressions/). Or you can implement it by yourself.

Comment: You don't need null-coalescing operator, addition operator for `string`s is compiled to `String.Concat` which can handle `null`s.

Comment: nope. It'll be compiled in usual string concatenation via "+" and in case one of values will be null whole string will be null.

Comment: Correct, I skipped the fact that expressions used for object creation will also be converted to SQL.

Comment: I mentioned this way in my question and the issue is that I need a dynamic and generic way for it because I have several classes that needs such selection and also each class maybe have diff concatenate field

Comment: @Hamid try this one, but it's better to create some dtos or viewmodels for each model you are using just to separate data layer and presentation layer